# Stored Procedure not returning value sometimes in node.js

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, stored-procedures

I have a mysql stored procedure that returns 1 if it is able to successfully execute two updates and insert and rolls everything back and returns 0 if if could not. Here is what it looks like:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`barrence`@`%` PROCEDURE `completed_procedure`(IN insubmissionid INT, OUT success INT)
BEGIN

DECLARE inbountyid INT;
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION ROLLBACK;
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING ROLLBACK;

START TRANSACTION;

SET success = 0;
SET @inbountyid = (SELECT idbounty FROM submission WHERE idsubmission = insubmissionid);

UPDATE submission SET status='a' WHERE idsubmission = insubmissionid;

IF (SELECT ROW_COUNT() = 1)
THEN UPDATE bounty SET iscomplete=1 WHERE idbounty = @inbountyid;
END IF;

IF (SELECT ROW_COUNT() = 1)
THEN INSERT INTO completion (idperson, idbounty, datecompleted, idsubmission, mediaid, description,
    privatestatus, contenttype, totalamount)  
SELECT s.idperson, s.idbounty, s.datesubmitted, s.idsubmission,
    COALESCE(s.youtubeid, s.contentid) AS mediaidid, b.description, b.privatestatus,
    b.contenttype, COALESCE(SUM(amount),0) AS totalamount 
FROM submission s 
INNER JOIN bounty b on s.idbounty = b.idbounty 
INNER JOIN contribution c on s.idbounty = c.idbounty 
WHERE s.idsubmission = insubmissionid AND c.ispaid = 1;
END IF;

IF (SELECT ROW_COUNT() = 1)
THEN SET success = 1;
END IF;

IF (success = 0)
THEN ROLLBACK;
END IF;

SELECT success;

COMMIT;
END
```

When I call this stored procedure inside of MySQL Workbench it seems to work correctly, executing all updates/insert and returning 1 or 0 if otherwise. However, when I call this stored procedure on my node.js server and console.log the result, it only returns the success variable if it is 1 but does not return it if 0. Here is how I am calling it:

```
db.acceptSubmission(submissionId, function(result) {
        console.log(result);
}

exports.acceptSubmission = function(submissionId, callback) {
    var sql = "CALL completed_procedure(?, @success)";
    var inserts = [submissionId];
    sql = mysql.format(sql, inserts);

    console.log("Running Admin Accept Submission Procedure: " + sql);

    dbcommon.executeStatement(pool, sql, callback);
};
```

Result looks like this when successful:

```
[ [ { success: 1 } ],
  { fieldCount: 0,
    affectedRows: 0,
    insertId: 0,
    serverStatus: 2,
    warningCount: 0,
    message: '',
    protocol41: true,
    changedRows: 0 } ]
```

And this when it's not:

```
{ fieldCount: 0,
  affectedRows: 0,
  insertId: 0,
  serverStatus: 2,
  warningCount: 0,
  message: '',
  protocol41: true,
  changedRows: 0 }
```

I am utterly stumped. What is going on?

Comment: Are you using a 3rd party mysql driver? If so, which one?

Comment: @scottjustin5000 https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is just the way the mysql module you are using behaves when it sees that result in that context.  I believe that since you know how to interpret the response, it is a non-issue in this case, and you will get expected results when you return a non-zero response in general.